# generate a binary file from a text file in linux shell

Tags: bash

I have a text file a.txt, inside which each line consists of 2 numbers, looks like this:

```
1234 5678
```

Now I want to convert a.txt's content from text into binary, which means the numbers won't be text anymore, but binary representation, which can be viewed by `od -tu4`.

How can I do that via `bash`?

Comment: Do you have specific binary representation in mind? If you choose the one where 'each digit is represented by a byte value containing the ASCII code of the digit', then it's pretty easy.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I mean I want to every number in the text file to be binary-ly represented, which means `1234` as one number, its binary takes 4 bytes.

Comment: There are many ways to represent number in "binary": BCD, byte per decimal digit, or simply convert to binary (in 1234 can be represented as two bytes only), but more questions: little endian or big endian ..... fixed size, prefixed with length ...

Comment: @OpDeCirkel, on intel arch, so I want little endian. And every number (not every digit) should simply be converted to binary taking 4 bytes, even it's less 2^16.

Comment: Are the inputs in hexadecimal then?

Comment: @James, sorry, what you mean by **inputs**?

Comment: The values in a.txt, are they hexadecimal or decimal values?

Comment: 1234 in its current textual form, is already a binary representation taking 4 bytes, but I assume you want a signed 32 bit little endian two complements integer value.

Comment: @GolezTrol, yes you are right, 32-bit little endian 2's complements. And yes, 1234 takes 4 bytes, but plz, a.txt may contain numbers such as 12345,1234567677....

Comment: You mean if you `od -tu4` you want to get `1234 5678`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a shell script that uses AWK to do what you want. Put the following into a file (hex2bin.awk):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function dec2bin(n){
  for(i=0;i < 4; i++){
    printf("%c", n % 256);
    n = int(n / 256);
  }
}
{ dec2bin($1); dec2bin($2);}
```

Make the file executable (`chmod a+x hex2bin.awk`)

Then run it:

```
./hex2bin.awk a.txt | od -tu4
0000000              1234            5678                                
0000010
```

This reads in two columns of decimal numbers represented in ASCII and prints them out into 32-bit little endian binary.